# I keep getting confused about proper encapsulation with regard to pointers, could someone take a look?

Tags: c++, pointers, encapsulation

I keep finding myself wanting to do things the right way™. However, I am a bit confused about data encapsulation (not the principle of it, but how to do it correctly in C++)

Let's say I have the following class:

```
template <class T, class Alloc = std::allocator<T> >
class Tree
{
public:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        T data;

        Node** get_children() const { return children; }
        Node*  get_parent() const { return parent; }
        Node*  get_right() const { return right; }

        friend class Tree;

    private:
        Node** children;
        Node*  parent;
        Node*  right;
    };

    // typedefs for STL ...

    class iterator // linear iterator
    {
        // ...
    };

    class const_iterator // linear iterator
    {
        // ...
    };

    // Tree operations ...

private:
    Node root;
};
```

I want the tree to be able to modify the structure of the nodes freely, so I made it a friend class to the node.

I also want the user to be able to traverse the tree as a tree (rather than using the tree structure for storage behind the scenes, and just letting the user iterate over it linearly).

The data should be freely modifiable. If the owner of the tree object doesn't want another user to modify its contents, it can pass a const reference.

Now I'm left wondering about the return types of my getter methods. Whatever happens, I don't want the user ever to be able to change the structural information of the node directly. The tree should always be the one modifying the private members. Will this code guarantee that? What if instead of a `Node**`, we save a `std::vector<Node*>` and return a const reference to the vector?

Comment: What is `T data`, are you using templates? Apart from that, basically you are killing encapsulation as you are not hiding your information, but make it freely available. If you want to omit the encapsulation (bad idea, maybe), use a struct, works like a class but is all public.

Comment: Correct. In fact, this class is inside the tree class, and the tree class is a template class which provides `T`.

Comment: As soon as you return raw pointers you are breaking encapsulation and you can expect trouble with allocation/deallocation since you are not relying on RAII. Getters and setters are too low level, how about abstracting node operations to a higher level and defining a public interface for the node? Also, using iterators to traverse the tree would be better than providing raw pointer methods.

Comment: Maybe you should add this in your code, just a little visualization.

Comment: I've added a bit more context to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two are secure:

```
Node*  get_parent() const { return parent; }
Node*  get_right() const { return right; }
```

Since these functions return pointers by value, the user cannot modify the member variables.

This one is unsafe:

```
Node** get_children() const { return children; }
```

This too returns a pointer by value, so that the user cannot modify `children`, but the user *can* modify the elements in the array, which I presume are pointers to children. Here's how to make it safe:

```
Node * const * get_children() const { return children; }
```

(And when you're ready, you can advance to STL containers and stop using arrays.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My actual code doesn't use an array like that, hence the continuation of the question with `std::vector<>` and returning a const reference. I was just hoping to learn a bit more about pointers while I'm at it.

Comment: @robrene: I'm all for experimenting to learn more about the basics. And yes, returning a const reference to `vector<Node*>` will work.